# Show that $P(\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_n)\leq \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(A_n) $

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to understand the following proof in the book A probability path by Sidney Resnick.
Given the probability space $(P,B,\Omega,)$, Suppose $A_n\in B$ for $n\geq 1$.

Fatou's Lemma: We have the following inequality:

$P(\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_n)\leq \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(A_n) \leq \limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(A_n) \leq P(\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_n)$

I first consider the first part:

$P(\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_n)\leq \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(A_n)$

The proof in the book starts with:
$P(\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_n)=P(\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\uparrow\bigcap\limits_{n\geq k} A_n))= \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\uparrow P (\bigcap\limits_{n\geq k} A_n)$.

We know that $P(\cap_{k\geq n}A_n)\leq P(A_n)$, therefore

$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\uparrow P (\bigcap\limits_{n\geq k} A_n)\leq \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(A_n)$.
My question is why not
$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\uparrow P (\bigcap\limits_{n\geq k} A_n)\leq \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(A_n)$ why we have to  consider $\liminf$ and why $\leq$ not equality?

Comment: A $\lim$it need not exist. That's what $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ are for. What does $\uparrow$ in your notation mean?

Comment: $\uparrow A_n$ denotes that the sequence $A_1,A_2,\dots$ is non-decreasing monotone sequence. Then why we use $\liminf$ not $\limsup$?Also, why the limit need not exist? I maybe wrong but it seems to me that $\cap_{k\geq n}A_n$ is monotone non-decreasing  and we know that limit of a monotone sequence of sets always exists.

Comment: Because $(A_n)$ might not be monotone but $(B_k)$ defined by $B_k=\bigcap\limits_{n\geq k} A_n$ is always nondecreasing.

Comment: thanks, so $B_k$ is non-decreasing, therefore $P(B_k)$ is non-decreasing, and that's why we use $\liminf$?